# Using SQL and regex, reverse first and last name on comma

Tags: mysql, regex, regexp-replace

This is something better suited for an actual programming language, not SQL and regex, but I'd love to know if it's actually feasible.

Background: I'm dealing with some tricky joins and cardinality as well as tables that don't have unique ids by way of numeric values (e.g. 0001). Just employee names (strings). I'm also dealing with a DB that doesn't support materialized views, so splitting into two columns and merging back together isn't a current option.

I have several tables with employee names listed in a column as last name, first name (e.g. Smith-Yates, John and Greene, Lynda) and one table with employee names listed as first name, last name (e.g. John Smith-Yates and Lynda Greene) in a column. Is there a way to use REGEXP() to swap the first and last names on the comma using MySQL -- also compensating for double-barreled last names?

Thanks for any insight you can provide.

Comment: You could find the position of the comma, take the substring from that to the end and then append the substring from the start to the comma location. There's probably better ways to do it, but give this a shot.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regular expressions for the task you describe. You can split strings using the [SUBSTRING_INDEX() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index).

Demo:

```
mysql> set @name = 'Smith-Yates, John';

mysql> select substring_index(@name, ',', 1) as last_name;
+-------------+
| last_name   |
+-------------+
| Smith-Yates |
+-------------+

mysql> select trim(substring_index(@name, ',', -1)) as first_name;
+------------+
| first_name |
+------------+
| John       |
+------------+
```

But there are inevitably cases that will spoil this like "Downy, Jr., Robert".

You should really store the first name and last name in separate columns, or else store them in a canonical format.

Comment: My guess is that the OP is trying to do exactly that, but is working with legacy data.